# LND errors after upgraded to v0.5.2

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, lightning-routing

Recently upgraded to the latest lnd version (following the stadicus guide) but once i restarted the client i keep getting this error when i check the logs:

*[ERR] LNWL: Failed to process consensus server notification (name: `blockconnected`, detail: `failed to store sync information 00000000000000000024cca7ae0fea5ae75fd1405a44e7fac08a94c03b19bbe4: failed to fetch block hash for height 563348: block not found*

[image]

I have all my channels inactive at the moment but the upgrade seemed to be worked as expected since

> lncli getinfo

prints the correct and latest version... Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: is your btcd / bitcoind running?

Comment: Yeh bitcoind was running smoothly, but i noticed this morning that it was all a matter of waiting around 1 hour for the client to synch properly... My panic mode and stubbornness yesterday didnt let me see the bigger picture.. This morning lnd is running as expected on the latest version and all my channels are open and active. Thanks as usual for your concern @RenePickhardt

Comment: sure you'r welcome I just gave an answer to summarize and give some context. have you considered opening and lnd issue on their github?

Answer (score 1):

Generally your lightning node needs to scan blocks from `bitcoind` or `btcd`. It seems like due to the fact that your node was offline `lnd` did not catch up processing the blocks provided by your bitcoin node. So it seems like you just have to wait until lnd catches up.

Comment: Indeed... hope this helps someone else in the future, these panic modes are not healthy at all. Thanks again.